# Getting unread message count from table messages and messages-seen

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, student-messages and student-messages-seen

My problem is I cannot get a query to run whereby I can say that globally '(user) has *4* unread messages'

[I've created a mysqlfiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hkHrESR9VNEoqhgXfkSi3r/0)

I *think* i've gotten the second query right, But I would like someone to confirm that its correct.  It produces the right number but I am not sure.  Please could someone help me achieve getting the two different counts correct?

Comment: show some sample data

Comment: is the table `student-messages` a sort of billboard that can be read by many students ? I ask because else if `student-messages` is a sort of inbox, then you simply can add a bool column to it.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is correct.  To make it global, just remove the thread id where condition.  You will want an index on student-messages recipient.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase your first query as follows (changes are commented):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `student-messages` t1 
LEFT JOIN `student-messages-seen` t2 
    ON t2.messageID = t1.id 
    AND t2.userID = t1.recipient    -- moved from the WHERE clause
WHERE 
    t1.recipient = 1001 
    -- AND t2.userID = 1001         -- moved to the ON part of the JOIN
    AND t2.id IS NULL               -- fiter on unread messages
ORDER BY t1.ts DESC;
```

The second query is essentially the same, with just an additional filter on the thread:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `student-messages` t1 
LEFT JOIN `student-messages-seen` t2 
    ON t2.messageID = t1.id 
    AND t2.userID = t1.recipient   
WHERE 
    t1.recipient = 1001 
    AND t1.thread = 69
    AND t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.ts DESC;
```